# Django Crispy Forms add HTML Attributes

Tags: python, django, forms, lastpass

My goal is to have LastPass ignore all input forms on my site.  I am using crispy forms and showing all form fields with only this in my HTML:

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

However, I want to edit some of the HTML attributes of all input elements created by this form WITHOUT writing each one individually.  LastPass recommends that I use `data-lpignore="true"` in my HTML `input` tags.  I tried to implement that in my form tags, but that didn't work (yes, I know, form != input). :

```
<form action="{{ action }}" method="post" class="no-ajax" data-lpignore="true">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
</form>
```

This didn't work.

I also tried including the following in `SETTINGS.py`:

```
CRISPY_CLASS_CONVERTERS = {'data-lpignore': 'true'}
```

Which is supposed to add `data-lpignore="true"` to my crispy form `input` tags according to crispy forms' [documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#change-crispy-forms-input-default-classes), but this didn't work.

Am I stuck doing individual input lines or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

In your form class, pass default attributes to the widget used to render your form fields. For example,

```
from django import forms

DEFAULT_ATTRS = {'data-lpignore': 'true'}
...
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=DEFAULT_ATTRS))
```